# Using Pydrive to query the files by modifiedTime

Tags: python-3.x, google-drive-api, google-cloud-platform, pydrive

i am using pydrive that trying to query the files from the date that i created.
here is my sample code:

```
    for f in drive.ListFile({'q':"modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'"}):
    for f1 in f:
        print(f1['title']+' '+f1['id'])
```

but while i run my code,
`googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=modifiedByMeDate+%3E+%272012-06-04T12%3A00%3A00-08%3A00%27&alt=json returned "Invalid query">` is returned.

is there something wrond in my query?
thanks everyone..

Comment: Is this information useful for you? https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters

Comment: Dear, thanks for your reply and i checked that link before.
and i directly copied the query of modified date "modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'" to my code and run, but same error is returned.

Comment: I'm sorry for the inconvenience. How about modifying from ``modifiedTime`` to ``modifiedDate``. Because you are using Drive API v2. But ``modifiedTime`` is used for Drive API v3. https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/search-parameters If this didn't work, can you provide your script?

Comment: Dear, Thanks your comment and now i can run this query without error!
I changed the query command from modifiedTime to modifiedDate!! :)

Answer (score 2):

This works for me:

```
# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10,
    fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)",
    q="modifiedTime > '2012-06-04T12:00:00-08:00'"
    ).execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Using the GDrive [Python Quickstart](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) as reference and using v3 of Drive API.

Comment: Dear, thanks for your comment but i am using pydrive to get the information from drive.
but - i think it is a stupid question, which one is better? using pydrive or google python api?

Comment: "PyDrive is a wrapper library of google-api-python-client that simplifies many common Google Drive API tasks." If the things you're doing is covered by PyDrive, no problem, I think someone just made life easier for you - just call them methods.  But if you wanna do more, you ought to learn the gritty details so you won't have to wait for the developer-who-wrote-the-wrapper's updates.

Comment: Dear, thanks for you comment and now i have a clearly concept of these stuff.
i will learn more and more and it seems like a long road...:)!